# Grapesjs with grapesjs-mjml plugin does not convert MJML to HTML

Tags: mjml, grapesjs

I just setup grapesjs editor by [example](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-mjml#readme) with mjml plugin and it simply does not convert MJML to HTML. Error is inside minified code of plugin.

I am using versions

- 0.18.4 grapesjs
- 0.6.0 grapesjs-mjml

**Chrome console**

```
grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at e.default (grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2:1267707)
    at e.default (grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2:10566)
    at d (grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2:1537200)
    at u (grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2:1576336)
    at Z.r.run (grapesjs-mjml.min.js:2:1576433)
    at Z.r.callRun (grapes.min.js:2:353040)
    at Object.runCommand (grapes.min.js:2:350114)
    at Object.run (grapes.min.js:2:349652)
    at Object.runCommand (grapes.min.js:2:883122)
    at EmailEditor.getHtml (EmailEditor.ts:132:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `<body>` tag which wraps mjml document. You need to remove this tag entirely. More info in existing [issue](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-mjml/issues/285) on gitgub.

Your mjml code is like this:

```html
<body>
  <mjml>
    <mj-head id="ilnn">
       <mj-raw>
       ...
  </mjml>
</body>
```

And it would be like this.

```html
<mjml>
  <mj-head id="ilnn">
    <mj-raw>
     ...
</mjml>
```

The solution is to override **wrapper** component *toHTML()* method.

```js
const editor = grapesJS.init(editorConfig);

editor.getWrapper().toHTML = function(opts) {
  return this.getInnerHTML(opts);
};
```